# How to Convert This Sql in LinQ

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Using this query I get my data which I want.

```
select * 
from tbl_project
join tbl_project_detail on tbl_project_detail.project_id = tbl_project.id
```

I need to know how I can use this SQL in Linq-to-SQL:

```
select SUM(pd.no_vacancy) as Number 
from tbl_project p
join tbl_project_detail pd on pd.project_id = p.id 
where p.id='1'
```

I also try it but it doesn't work.

```
var result = (from p in db.tbl_projects
              join c in db.tbl_project_details on p.id equals c.project_id
              where c.project_id == type
              select new { c.no_vacancy }).Sum();
```

Please help me.. I am stuck :(

Comment: This is no conversion service. What did you try and where did you fail?

Comment: @naveengoyal: Please make only substancial edits. Your edits have to be reviewed by other people. If the changes are small that only generates more work than it solves.

Comment: @juergend I am Beginner in sql and Linq.

Comment: @MehediHasan - `beginner` would imply you are starting (and trying) to learn something. You are just asking for a translation. Try and break down what you want and read the documentation. i.e You know you need to select, you know you need to sum etc.

Comment: +1 for showing what you have tried - The question is now valid IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be help you:

```
from p in tbl_project 
join pd in tbl_project_detail on project_id equals p.id
where p.id=1
select new 
{ 
    sum(pd => pd.no_vacancy) 
};
```

Comment: No.

 It Do Not Work .. :(

Comment: I have modified let me know.

Answer (score 0):

At Last I Solve My Problem By Using This

> ```
>   var result = (from p in db.tbl_projects
>                   join
>                       c in db.tbl_project_details on p.id equals c.project_id
>                   where c.project_id == type
>                   select (int)c.no_vacancy ).Sum();
> ```

Thank You Everyone For Helping Me.. :)